# Provide upper bound

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality

Suppose we have data $x\sim \mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal D$ is unknown. $g$ and $g'$ are two bounded functions. Note $G=\mathbb E (g(x))$ and $G'=\mathbb E (g'(x))$. We also have the Monte-Carlo empirical estimation with $m$ samples: $\hat G = \Sigma_i \frac 1 m g(x_i), \hat {G'} = \Sigma_i \frac 1 m g'(x_i)$.

Is there a way to upper bound the probability $P[\text{sgn}(\hat{G}-\hat{G'})=\text{sgn}(G-G')]$? i.e. the probability of the empirical estimations correctly predict the sign of the difference between the expectations.

The lower bound is easy: just consider the case where they are both close to their empirical observations and use concentration inequality. i.e. let $\epsilon =\left|\hat{G}-\hat{G}^{\prime}\right| / 2$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left(\operatorname{sgn}\left(G-G^{\prime}\right)=\operatorname{sgn}\left(\hat{G}-\hat{G}^{\prime}\right)\right) & \left.\geq \mathbb{P}(|G-\hat{G}| \leq \epsilon) \cap\left(\left|\hat{G}^{\prime}-G^{\prime}\right| \leq \epsilon\right)\right) \\
& \geq(1-\mathbb{P}(|G-\hat{G}| \geq \epsilon))\left(1-\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\hat{G}^{\prime}-G^{\prime}\right| \geq \epsilon\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Can you explicit a bit more how $G,G',\hat G$ and $\hat G'$ are defined ? Also I guess it would help if you explained how you got the lower bound (and what the lower bound you found is)

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question hopefully it's more clear now. Let me know if anything is still missing!

Comment: I believe OP has improved this question sufficiently for it to be reopened.